# MFMailComposeViewController image attachment broken icon and rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm taking a picture using the UIImagePickerController, and I want to attach it to an email. I've been able to do that successfully, it attaches when the email sends and comes through okay, but there are two small issues.

1. the image doesn't show up in the mail composer view on the iPhone. Instead the user sees an outlined bounding box with the blue '?' broken image icon. Could this be because of my setup?: I don't actually save the image to the user's phone, I just place it as a UIImage in an NSMutableArray, and pull it from that to attach it. I have a hunch that the composer view looks for a saved image to pull the thumbnail, and it isn't finding it. Could that be the case?
2. the image comes through (in the mailbox that receives it) with a 90 CCW rotation. It's on its side. This could be a problem at the sending stage and I just can't see it due to issue #1, and I'm hopeful if you guys can help me solve #1, that #2 would resolve itself (two birds with one stone)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well to debunk my own theory...I now have it set up to take up to 3 images and attach them all, using the same NSMutableArray method, and it attaches all 3, but the last one actually does show up in the composer view (without saving) as a preview. Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: I solved #2. Turns out for whatever reason I was inputting the image into the array right side up, but it was coming out with UIImageOrientationLeft, so I used the code found here to rotate it manually: https://gist.github.com/1531596. But I'm still at a loss for issue #1.

Comment: You ever figure out #1?